# SyntaxError Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have that error:

> SyntaxError Unexpected token, expected ",")

Code:

```
 render() {
        const {collections} = this.state;
        return (
           
            <div className='shop-page'>
                {
                  collections.map({id, ...otherCollectionProps} => {
                      <PreviewCollection key={id} {...otherCollectionProps}/>
                  })
                }
            </div>
          
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses are needed around destructured parameters.

```
({ id, ...otherCollectionProps }) => ()
```

You should also return the JSX with either `return` or with simple parentheses as well (instead of curly braces).

```
const { collections } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="shop-page">
    {collections.map(({ id, ...otherCollectionProps }) => {
      return <PreviewCollection key={id} {...otherCollectionProps} />;
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!